# UNIX - grep files based on permission

Tags: unix, grep

I have a very specific request. I have a directory with a lot of files, all with varying permissions.

I want to identify all files that any user (user group other) can read, but I need to use grep. (I know there is better ways than grep but this is a special request)

My directory name is `testfiles`. I am thinking along the following lines:

```
ls /testfiles | grep -E <<insert more>>
```

Can someone advise me?

Comment: If you have access to GNU find, take a look at `-perm` option.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the that & perm does not work in my environment.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls -l testfiles | grep "^.r..r..r"
```

In permissions check whether user, group and other all have Read (r) permission or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use try this.
As. - dot represents a single character

```
ls -l /testfiles | grep -E "^.r..r..r.."
```